# How to write others language text like gujarati and hindi?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

plugin name: bluetooth_print:

LineText(type: LineText.TYPE_TEXT, content: 'સવાર'));

I have write like this but whenever i will click print button then we are getting numeric value in slip.

I want to print gujarati and hindi text in print slip.

Demo Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irqr4.jpg)

Comment: HINT: ask it to chatGPT

Comment: We need more context. You tagged this question with flutter and bluetooth but there is no mention of anything bluetooth related. I guess you want to print to a bluetooth printer. Please [edit] your question and add information about the printer and the library you use to communicate with it.

Comment: I am using  bluetooth_print: plugin

Comment: @lalit thanks for the information. The plugin seems not to be very active, the last change was made about 10 months ago and there are multiple [open issues](https://github.com/thon-ju/bluetooth_print/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+language) regarding other languages. Their [github page](https://github.com/thon-ju/bluetooth_print) states that you can reach them via the QQ instant messenger, maybe try it this way

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.